# Is there a way to fetch the external IP address of the VM from node using any npm or Google cloud API?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I want to fetch the IP Address of my Google VM Instance dynamically using node. Is there any NPM package or does Google Cloud provide any API? I dont want to manually copy-paste it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [Node.js Client library for Google Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/compute/0.11.x/).

There are several ways to retrieve the external IP address of a compute instance, for example you can run this code:

```
const Compute = require('@google-cloud/compute');
const compute = new Compute({
  projectId: 'your-project-id',
  keyFilename: '/your/path/to/file'
});
const zone = compute.zone('instanceZone');
const vm = zone.vm('instanceName');

vm.getMetadata(function(err, metadata, apiResponse) {});

//-
// If the callback is omitted, we'll return a Promise.
//-
vm.getMetadata().then(function(data) {
  // Representation of this VM as the API sees it.
  const metadata = data[0];
  console.log(metadata.networkInterfaces[0].accessConfigs[0].natIP)
});
```

Also, you can use the [Google Cloud Platform command-line interface](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/).

`gcloud compute instances describe instanceName --zone=instanceZone | grep natIP`

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Any type-safe version of this lib? 

Comment: @OliverDixon GCP libraries are autogenerated and notoriously awful. For getting the external IP address, you can use `gcp-metadata` npm package instead. 
`const externalIp = await gcpMetadata.instance('network-interfaces/0/access-configs/0/external-ip');`

Comment: @JakS indeed, I'm having many headaches with this platform tbh.

Comment: I think this method is no longer available

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility is to leverage the metadata service.  See the following documentation for details:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata

At the highest level, GCP keeps metadata about each VM instance which includes your external IP address.  By making a REST call to a special endpoint, you can self request all your metadata.  This is returned as a JSON document that can be then be easily parsed.

As an example, run the following at the shell prompt inside your VM:

```
wget --output-document=- --header="Metadata-Flavor: Google" \
  --quiet http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/network-interfaces/0/access-configs/0/external-ip
```

Hopefully you will see that by making this REST request, we are pretty much language neutral and hence if you can make a REST request from your favorite language, you can retrieve your desired data (and more).  If you don't use this technique for your current needs, be sure and keep it in mind for future items where you need other data.

Answer (score 1):

As an addendum to @llompalles answer, this function may help some folks who prefer the async / await pattern:

```
const getIpAddress = async (vm) => {
    const metadata = await vm.getMetadata();
    return metadata[0].networkInterfaces[0].accessConfigs[0].natIP;
};
```

Example Usage - Respond with the IP address of the VM that was Started:

```
const Compute = require('@google-cloud/compute');
const [serverName, region] = ["server_name", "us-west1-a"];

exports.startVMInstance = async (req, res) => {
    const compute = new Compute();
    const zone = compute.zone(region);
    const vm = zone.vm(serverName);

    const startVmResponse = await vm.start();
    const ip = await getIpAddress(vm);
    res.status(200).send(`Server successfully started at IP address: ${ip}`);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The methods mentioned above have been deprecated if you try you will get following error:

```
> const compute = new Compute();
Uncaught TypeError: Compute is not a constructor
```

Now we can follow below method to get the public ip of remote compute instance resource

```
const {InstancesClient} = require('@google-cloud/compute').v1;
const computeClient = new InstancesClient();
const the_compute_instance = await computeClient.get({instance: "<instance-name>", project: "<gcp-project-name>", zone: "<gcp-zone>"})
const public_ip = the_compute_instance[0]["networkInterfaces"][0]["accessConfigs"][0]["natIP"]
console.log(public_ip)
```

[GCP Reference](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-node/blob/main/packages/google-cloud-compute/samples/generated/v1/instances.get.js)